# File upload Not Working with PHP

Tags: php, file

So I have a form that allows a user to upload files. When they submit the file, I can get the file information such as `name` and `tmp_name`, yet the actually upload doesn't work. I don't get any PHP errors either. Below is my code, I think I just need another pair of eyes on it, as it was working a few days ago.

```
//Get the file name
$target_Dir = "temp/";

$tempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$target_file = $target_Dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$filename = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

//Get the password
$password = $_POST['password'];
//Store if the user wants the certificate to remain password protected
$passProtect = $_POST['passProtect'];
//upload the file to the server
move_uploaded_file($tempName, $target_file);
```

I need the file name without the extension for a later point in my code, in case you're wondering why I'm storing the file name without the extension.

Comment: Nope, cause they are in double quotes and that is very much acceptable but not a neat way to code though. What is your maximum file upload in php.ini? Are you sure the file is actually uploaded?

Comment: Does your form opening tag have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: With double quotes, PHP will take the value off the variable, and not interpret it as a literal string. I just added an `echo $filename` and it outputted the correct output. Test file was `index.html`, it outputted `index`

Comment: @andre3wap Yes it does

Comment: There has to be something in the error logs in regards to what's going on,  can you add this to the top of the page? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: what does `print $_FILES['file']['error']` say?

Comment: Dang... I feel stupid. I had an unlink set later on in my script that unlinks the file being uploaded. I don't know why I had it, but I did. Thanks for your extra eyes guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an `unlink()` further down in my script for some reason that I can't remember. It deleted the file that the user would upload right away.

Thanks for the extra set of eyes guys.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just did this mistake

```
$fileExtension = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Try using this insted of that Code then only you will get the file name not the extention.

Comment: why would anyone want to store the filename in a variable called fileExtension?  unless being cryptic is the point...

Comment: I didn't know of that you could just use `PATHINFO_FILENAME` Thanks, but that doesn't solve my uploading issue, although your code has been added, will edit above code.

Comment: might be in his case he wants to display the Name of the file but not the extention... abd YES the variable name Is a Little Confusing.

Comment: I can't seem to see the issue with the upload. After adjusting my code with yours, still nothing. The only thing I can think of is if the folder doesn't have write access, but it's on a local wamp server, so it should by default.

Comment: @CaptainQuint *"should"* isn't enough. Check it, edit it, and make sure it does have write permissions.

Comment: @Martin it was a random `unlink()` further down in my code. All is working now.